# Multiple Futures in Play and using case classes to hold the future data

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

The scenario:

I have two different Api calls to make (across the web). ApiCall1, ApiCall2. Eventually ApiCall1 will return an Option[Catalogue] and ApiCall2 will return a Seq[Catalogue]

I then need to take these two and build a FrontPage object. During the instantiation of the FrontPage object it creates a Seq[NewProducts]. Everytime it makes a NewProduct the NewProduct must also call a MongoDB across the web inside a Future. Every Future must have completed prior to handing the FrontPage object off to the view.

Here is the code for the FrontPage class:

```
case class FrontPage(maybeCat1: Option[Catalogue], maybeCat2: Seq[Catalogue]) {

   val newProducts:Seq[NewProduct] = {
       maybeCat2.map( { cat =>
           NewProduct(cat)
       })
   } 
}
```

Here is the code so far for the NewProduct class:

```
case class NewProduct(cat:Catalogue) {
    val indivProduct:Option[IndivProduct] = {

        // ??? 
        // This next line goes out to Mongo and returns a Future[List[JsObject]]
        val indiv:Future[List[JsObject]] = MongoFetch.getIndivProduct(cat)

        //need to strip out the 'Future', wait for it to return?
        val listJS = indiv .. ???? // <-- need just the List[JsObject]]

        return IndivProduct(listJs)  // <-- constructs a new Option[IndivProduct]

    }
}
```

Here is the code so far for the controller:

```
def landing() = Action.async {
   for {
      catalogue1 <- models.Granite.getCatalogue("front-page") // <- ApiCall1
      catalogue2 <- models.Granite.getCatalogue("tags")  // <- ApiCall2

   } yield {

      //??? How to now build the FrontPage object
      // surely it also depends on the future? 
      val fp = FrontPage(catalogue1, catalogue2)

      Ok(views.html.frontpage.landing(fp))  // <- at this point all futures must have returned.
   }
}
```

I really want to be able to pass a nice neat FrontPage object to the View (and hence the designers) with a really simple set of function defined on it for them to template with. All the futures must return. Catalogue1 and Catalogue2 are not dependent on anything or even each other. Creating a Seq[NewProducts] inside the FrontPage object is depending on both of them having returned. And I can not then pass the FrontPage object to the view until it to has returned the NewProducts from Mongo.

This level of complexity is above what I am used to. I am getting confused with where and when to use for/yield comprehensions. I am afraid that this will somehow just block because the Futures are too far embedded in a case class, within a case class. The very top level of the controller is wrapped in an Async, so will this mean that any and all Futures within that Async call will be non-blocking?

Comment: Can you avoid doing this work in your constructors? I.e., move it to a constructor method that returns a `Future[NewProduct]`?

Comment: @TravisBrown - the problem with that is I really want to pass a whole, fully complete FrontPage through to the View.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the futures as steps to get to a fully complete front page, not parts of it and think what each little part of those steps would be.

For example, to construct an instance of NewProduct, create a method that talks to the db and returns the future completed NewProduct instances.

```
case class NewProduct(cat:Catalogue, indiv: Option[IndivProduct]) 

def newProductFor(cat: Catalogue): Future[NewProduct] = 
  for {
    listJs <- MongoFetch.getIndivProduct(cat)
  } yield NewProduct(cat, IndivProduct(listJs))
```

You can then create your front page, again, in a function/method that handles the loading/future:

```
case class FrontPage(
  maybeCat1: Option[Catalogue], 
  maybeCat2: Seq[Catalogue], 
  newProducts: Seq[NewProduct]) 

def loadFrontPage: Future[FrontPage] = 
  for {
    catalogue1 <- models.Granite.getCatalogue("front-page")
    tags <- models.Granite.getCatalogue("tags")
    newProducts <- loadNewProducts(tags)
  } yield FrontPage(catalogue1, tags, newProducts)


def loadNewProducts(catalogues: Seq[Catalogue]): Future[Seq[NewProduct]] = {
  Future.traverse(catalogues) { catalogue => 
    newProductFor(catalogue) 
  }
}
```

Note Future.traverse which takes a collection with A:s in and a function that goes from A => Future[B] and returns a Future[collection[B]].

You can then call that in an async controller to feed to a template:

```
 def page() = Action.async { 
   for {
     frontPage <- loadFrontPage
   } yield Ok(views.some.template(frontPage))
 }
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that is very helpful. Just one thing for others reading this, in loadNewProducts I believe it is meant to be catalogue => newProductFor(catalogue) rather than NewProduct.createFrom(catalogue). I got this to work! Thanks